# Is there a way to get access to a variable outside of a for loop block

Tags: c++, scope

Is there a way to get access to a variable outside of a for loop block?

```
int seedOffset;

// Loop through the asteroids and give them some starting orientation by using the random values 
for(std::vector<Asteroid*>::iterator asteroid = asteroids.begin(); asteroid != asteroids.end(); ++asteroid) 
{
    ( *asteroid )->posZ = -3.0;
    ( *asteroid )->rotX = GenerateRandomNumber( seedOffset, LOW, HIGH );
    ( *asteroid )->rotY = GenerateRandomNumber( seedOffset, LOW, HIGH );
    ( *asteroid )->rotZ = GenerateRandomNumber( seedOffset, LOW, HIGH );
    ( *asteroid )->initialSceneZRotation = GenerateRandomNumber( seedOffset, LOW, HIGH );
    seedOffset += 100;
}
```

Error:

```
Error   2   error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'seedOffset' used c:\**\game.cpp  53  1   Game
```

Comment: Read the error message, it doesn't say you can't access the variable.

Comment: Do you think I didn't read the error message ;) ? I didn't understand what it meant brah. I had assumed that because it was int, it would just increase as a number, I did not know you had to instantiate at 0.

Comment: So then ask "what does this error mean?" not "how do I access this variable?" and maybe try searching the web for "error C4700" which tells you the answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axhfhh6x.aspx

Comment: Have you finished asserting your ego? thank you for the help all.

Comment: Pointing out you can find the answer using a search engine has nothing to do with my ego. Stackoverflow is not meant to be a substitute for thinking and attempting to solve your own problem, and learning to search for what errors mean is a useful skill.

Comment: I was angry because I had already spent the best part of an hour trying to understand why it thought something was uninitialised... it's quite obvious now you point it out, but for some reason the error wasn't helping me. I am new to C++ of course, but i'm not new to reading errors... and, well.. took it to heart. please accept my apology. keep up the good work. And ofcourse, I did google the error. When you're relatively new to a language it's a real ball ache trying to see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message tells all !

```
int seedOffset = 0; //Initialize the variable before use
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly, the error message does not tell all if you are unsure of what it means. Thanks for the help. I had assumed that because it was int, it would just increase as a number, I did not know you had to instantiate at 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the seedOffset variable to avoid the error.

```
int seedOffset = 0;
```